# webpack, webpack-obfuscator and webpack-cli version hell

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, yii2-advanced-app

This must be one of the most tiresome conundrums a web developer can delve into.
I can ask a straigthtforward question right here however:

Which versions of the three mentioned.
(webpack, webpack-obfuscator and (possibly )webpack-cli)
ensure that it all works together?
if you know, you can stop reading here,
and (please) give an answer, or you can read on:

I have a Yii2 php app, with npm/javascript/React frontend support. I do:

```
composer install,
npm install,
npm run build.
```

When this is done from scratch (fresh clone from Github, caches cleared), it almost always ends up with npm run build giving this:

```
Error: The number of constructor arguments in the 
derived class t must be >= than the number of 
constructor arguments of its base class."
```

NOTE: I am completely happy just to have this issue fixed, so it all builds. Not sure of the webpack-cli part coming up (if you read on).
And NOTE again: This problem occurs in Windows 10, when I try to build a local version. All works well in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04).

We now have in package.json:

```
"webpack": "^2.4.1",
"webpack-obfuscator": "^0.17.3"
```

I then try higher versions of webpack-obfuscator until this error ceases, but instead there is another error (!):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
```

So, then I figure: maybe we can test higher versions of webpack as well?

I do that, but then comes another error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli'...
```

(So again, I am not sure it's something I need, I belive I answered yes to some yes/no question coming up)

There are zillions of versions, and I am now sick & tired of it. This problem has haunted me the last years.
Now this day I decided to go to the bottom with it once and for all. I have spent 6 hours, and I failed.
So very thankful for an answer, somebody must have experience from this...